# List of checkboxes not getting selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a checkbok as selectAll

Select All

```
<input class="all-select" type="checkbox" value="" name="">
```

i also have a list of friends with a checkbox each which is populated dynamically.

```
<ul>
    <li><span><img src="img.src" ></span><strong>Name</strong>
        <br />Email
        <input name="" type="checkbox" value="" class="chk-box">
    </li>.....</ul>
```

when i click the select all checkbox, then all the checkboxes of my list should get selected, the javascript code for which is given below :

```
$("#slide_top_pop").on("click", ".all-select", function (event) {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('input.chk-box').attr('checked', true);
    } else {
        $('input.chk-box').attr('checked', false);
    }
});
```

Now the problem is this that when i first time select the Select All check box then the list get selected but when i unchecked it and check again then the list is not selected  and when i tried to verify it on Mozilla what is the checked property(attribute) for the list then i get this :

```
 <input class="chk-box" type="checkbox" value="" name="" checked="checked">
```

which says that the checkbox is selected but i cant see the selected **tick** in the list.
I dont understand what the problem is .
any solution is appreciated thanks.

Comment: Are you using the custom checbox (like which use image on top of default checkbox)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of `.attr()` like:

```
$("#slide_top_pop").on("click", ".all-select", function (e) {
    $('input.chk-box').prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

Comment: While this is important `.attr('checked', true)` will check the checkbox: http://jsfiddle.net/ZhPZC/.